# Converting json object into array, after fetching using async/await?

Tags: javascript, json, async-await

I am trying to convert a Jsonobj that i fetched using async/await into an array, i have been doing it like this:

```
const apiurl = 'https://api.wheretheiss.at/v1/satellites/25544';

async function getArray(){
  var arr= [];
  const response = await fetch(apiurl);
  const jsonobject = await response.json();

  for(var i in jsonobject){
      arr.push(i, jsonobject[i]);
  }

  console.log(arr);
}
```

I am trying to make an object inside an array for every marker that is saved on my json, right now the json contains one marker, with the coordinates of the ISS. For example: {['iss','coordinates'],['harz',coordinates],...}

The code gives me an array of length 26 looking like this: ['name','iss','lat','45'....], but i would like an array of length 1 looking like this: ['name:iss, Lat:45, Lng:32'], the array should contain 1 element for every marker that im saving in my json.

Comment: You have to also `await` the call to `response.json()`.

Comment: the array now has length 26,  it split the object into its variables, even though i wanted to split it into single json objects containing these 26 variables

Comment: Update your answer to show *exactly* what your object looks like. It's not clear at present.

Comment: After your edit, it **isn't clear what you actually want**. Include what output you expect to see, what output you *actually* see, and what input leads to that (e.g. a sample of the returned JSON from the API you're calling.

Comment: @KarlMaxJander: What is the actual response you're getting from the URL?  Is it what you expect?  Are you confused on the difference between `for ... of` and `for ... in`?  (Which is a common mistake.)

Comment: @KarlMaxJander: Based on the updated question... If `jsonobject` is an object and you just want to put that object in an array, wouldn't that simply be this?: `var arr = [jsonobject];`  Instead of trying to describe your intent with potentially mixed up terminology, *show*  your intent.  *Show* the exact data you're getting in the response and *show* the exact result you're trying to build from that data.

Comment: You are literally getting an array of strings like `['name','iss','lat','45'.]`, and you want an array with a single string like `['name:iss, Lat:45, Lng: 32']`? WHY? And if that *isn't* what you want, then why did you give that as an example?

Comment: @JaredSmith hey sorry if my thinking is off, im very new to coding, i updated my question hopefully its easier to understand. I want this array to have an entry for very marker that i want to place on the map, so i can itterate of the array and place them on the map

Comment: @KarlMaxJander: *"right now the json contains one marker, with the coordinates of the ISS. For example: {['iss','coordinates'],['harz',coordinates],...}"* - That is not at all what that URL returns when I test it.  *"i would like an array of length 1 looking like this: ['name:iss, Lat:45, Lng:32']"* - The answer currently posted below provides exactly that.  I'm afraid your ongoing edits are not clear, and you appear to very confused regarding (1) the data you have and (2) the data you want.  Now would be a good time for you to observe the data you have and demonstrate the data you want.

Comment: ill try getting better into the terminology and i will improve my question once i have

Comment: @KarlMaxJander if you're new to coding then let me start here: **computers are *extremely* literal and picky**. Because of that, in order to work with them, we have to be too. Write out, in a **code block** (not plain text) ***exactly*** what you are getting as a JSON response (copy/pasted from your terminal/browser console), ***exactly*** what output your code is giving you, and ***exactly*** what output you want to see instead. Do not write a quicky incomplete thing that isn't what you want and expect that we (or the machine) will somehow intuit what you actually meant.

Comment: Note: it's an `Object`, not some made up `jsonobj` ... you simply have an `Object`

Answer (score 0):

It's a strange array structure, but based on your description this should work:

```
const arr = [
  Object.entries(jsonobject)
    .map(entry => entry.join(':'))
    .join(', ')
];
```

Comment: now it has 13 entries looking like this:( 0
: 
"name,iss"
1
: 
"id,25544"
2
: 
"latitude,-50.162317821405"
3
: 
"longitude,143.227578769"
4
: 
"altitude,435.44013467545"
5
: 
"velocity,27540.922939448"
6
: 
"visibility,daylight"
7
: 
"footprint,4585.1962761997"
8
: 
"timestamp,1706729215"
9
: 
"daynum,2460341.3103588"
10
: 
"solar_lat,-17.356020741113"
11
: 
"solar_lon,251.62110099936"
12
: 
"units,kilometers"
length
: 
13), but all this data should be in a single entry

Comment: @KarlMaxJander updated as an array with 1 big string.

Comment: how do i do that

Comment: thank you, i also updates my question, maybe its more understandable like this, im very new to cooding, so sorry if its hard to understand

Comment: @KarlMaxJander the above answer roughly matches what you asked for. If it's not correct, you need to do a better job showing: 1) Input data (remove the fetch call just show an example with an embedded data structure) 2. Intended output, exactly written out as correct javacript and 3. The output you are getting. If you can't do this it's going to be hard for people to help you along.

Comment: ill try once i can ask a new question or something